# How to reverse childnodes of a XML nodes using C#

Tags: c#, xml, reverse, nodes

I want to set reverse order of child nodes of given XML nodes.

How to do this???

```
 <Parent>
   <Child1>  </Child1>
   <Child2>  </Child2>
 </Parent>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<Parent>
<Child2>  </Child2>
<Child1>  </Child1>
</Parent>
```

EDIT:
I have simple XML file like above.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(value);
XmlElement docElement = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
```

I just want this XmlElement in reverse order.

**NOTE: I am using VS-2008 2.0**

Comment: You need to indicate exactly what type of XML Serializer you are using...

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C#3 / NET 3.5 then you can use [LinqToXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) and something like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("data.xml"));
var reversed = xdoc.Descendants("Parent").Descendants().Reverse();
```

Comment: This was going to be my exact same suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

"

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("data.xml"));
var reversed = xdoc.Descendants("Parent").Descendants().Reverse();

"

Does it work for above question ?